# Pandas: collapse values of columns to lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` object and I want to collapse it into a single row such that the values of each former column are turned to lists.

Is there a cheaper way to do this rather than using `.agg` and passing a dictionary with each column name assigned to `list`?

This is what my data looks like:

| index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | D |
| 1 | B | E |

This is the output I want:

| index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [A,B] | [D,E] |

Note: Index is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                   'col2':['F','G','H','I','J']})
print(df)

  col1  col2
0    A     F
1    B     G
2    C     H
3    D     I
4    E     J
```

1. Vectorized way to collapse columns:

```py
# Turn the columns to an index and drop the old one
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
# Turn the values of each column into lists and transpose the result
df.groupby(df.index).apply(list).to_frame().transpose()
```

2. Collapse columns to lists using a `for` loop:

```py
# Create a dummy data frame to fill in
df2 = df[0:1].copy()
# Fill in the dataset with the collapsed columns
for col in df.columns:
    df2.loc[0, col] = df[col].tolist()
```

Both solution lead to this result:

```py
              col1             col2
0  [A, B, C, D, E]  [F, G, H, I, J]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer first of all. Not really, I don't want to explode the values into the columns but I want to collapse them all together into a list. I added an example in the question to make it easier :)

Comment: @Guido Oh, I see. I updated the answer. I think there's a pandas function that does this but I cannot remember it at this moment. Let me know if my solution works though. Good luck (;

Comment: @Guido Glad it worked. I'll think about how to vectorize this solution throughout the day. I'll post a comment when I edit the answer.

Comment: Repost: actually deleted instead of modifying the above comment! Repost >>

Hi @Arturo Sbr , sorry I paused a bit the project meanwhile. I tested it and it does its job. I tried to understand whether I could have applied the same command to all columns like through a `df.apply(func=list, axis=1, result_type="broadcast)` command because I get an error related to ndarrays and the dtype, even though I forced all dtypes to `object` just before to avoid collisions. 
It actually would be nicer "vectorize" this operation but I don't find any other way other than looping each column so far as well.

Comment: Hey @Guido. I'm happy to announce I found a vectorized solution. Check it out above. In summary, I turned the columns to a horizontal index, grouped by that index, turned the values of each group to lists and turned to result to a data frame.

Comment: Super nice! Thanks!! I see I still have a mountain to climb about Pandas :)